# Web Service or Windows Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, windows-services

So good day to all.

I have a site and I want to make connection that can view our SQL Server (Windows SQL Server 2008). A programmer suggested to make a service. I don't know which one to use a windows service or a web service.

If I will be able to make a service how to apply it to my site? I have been searching about it but I can't find any resource.

If you guys have another solution in mind I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `I want to make connection that can view our SQL Server` this is not clear. Can you provide more details? It would be better if you can give example of the scenario which you want to resolve.

Comment: the service will be use as a  connection of the site to the database for fetching data or the service will be the one that fetch the data and the sites get the results.. That's currently my idea of how it will work.. Sorry for the noob question..

Comment: Changing your site to directly connect to the database to get the result would be simple solution. If that's not possible, you can have a REST API which will connect to the database to get the data and the site communicates with the API to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **REST API** that connects to the database and fetches you all the data that you need for your website., like

You can find simple examples on how a REST API can be created from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api) link.

And simultaneously you can fetch the data from the REST API like:

```
    static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            "api/products", product);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // return URI of the created resource.
        return response.Headers.Location;
    }
```

You can find complete example in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) link.